# Appstore Customer Review Download

Tags: php, app-store, review

I need customer reviews from apps as .txt, .xml, .csv to work with them.

So far I used the following .php script:
http://tellini.info/2011/07/scraping-app-store-reviews-page-after-page/
But unfortunately its not working anymore, I guess apple changed something

I guess apple changed the link to the reviews, because:

Not working: https://itunes.apple.com/customer-reviews/id458034879?displayable-kind=30&page=0

Working: /rss/customerreviews/id=458034879/xml

Since im not capable of writing php: 
Is anyone able to repair(/help to repair) this script or provide me with another free to use solution?

Comment: to give further informations:
today, i was able to execute the script twice without any changes. Now its not working again.
Somehow the link https://itunes.apple.com/customer-reviews/id458034879?displayable-kind=30&page=0 iseems to work just from time to time. Anyone can confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with apple servers. its working again.